# Query elasticsearch nested field by index(order of insert)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-nested

I have an elasticsearch document with some nested objects(mapped as nested field)
for example:

```json
{
  "FirstName": "Test",
  "LastName": "Test",
  "Cost": 322.54,
  "Email": "test@test.com",
  "Vehicles": [
    {
      "Year": 2000,
      "Make": "Mazda",
      "Model": "6"
    },
    {
      "Year": 2012,
      "Make": "Ford",
      "Model": "F150"
    }
  ]
}
```

i am trying to do aggregations on specific index of the array, for example i want to sum the cost of documents which has Ford make but **only** on the first vehicle.

is it even possible at all? there is almost no information on the internet about elasticsearch nested fields and nothing about their index/order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve what you want, but you also need to add the index order as a field inside your nested documents:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Test",
  "LastName": "Test",
  "Cost": 322.54,
  "Email": "test@test.com",
  "Vehicles": [
    {
      "Year": 2000,
      "Make": "Mazda",
      "Model": "6",
      "Index": 0
    },
    {
      "Year": 2012,
      "Make": "Ford",
      "Model": "F150",
      "Index": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

And then you can query your index using the two conditions on `Index` and the `Make` like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Vehicles",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "Vehicles.Index": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "Vehicles.Make": "Ford"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this specific case, the query is not going to yield any results, as you expect.

Comment: yes i agree with you, that a solution i also tought about, but i am trying to figure out if there is a way to do it without changing the data because there is already a lot of data in the DB

Comment: unfortunately not, because each nested document is a standalone (yet hidden) document, it has no idea that it is part of an "array" containing other siblings, hence why you need to give each document the "knowledge" of where it is located in the parent array.... It's very easy to leverage the `_update_by_query` API to update all documents in place without reindexing everything.

Comment: i did not had time to check the _update_by_query idea but it sound good i hope its really possible, anyway the bottom line of my issue is that elasticsearch not saving anywhere the order of nested documents so its impossible to do it without adding index field